# How can I make it so external media can only be mounted read-only on Kubuntu?

Tags: mount, kubuntu, automount

I want to make it so that any inserted media may only be mounted read-only, in a way it's only remountable as read-write by root. Is that possible? I'm guessing it could be possible with udev/polkit or something like that, but couldn't find anything about it, and have no clue where to start.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question has an excellent answer by @Braiam [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119853/how-can-i-create-a-udev-rule-to-mount-a-usb-drive-read-only)

Comment: I'm using Kubuntu, so I have Dolphin, not Nautilus. Does it also use GVFS? I couldn't find it in it's dependencies...